# How to update bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, razor, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap datepicker on loading paging start date is meant ot be 2 days from current datebut when a value is selected from dropdown start date that can be selected should be of 7days after from current date

```
$("#CaseType").change(function () {

        if ($("#CaseType".val == "Plan_Only")) {

            var conOprDate1 = AddDays(7);
            alert(conOprDate1);

           // $('#OperationDate').datepicker('startDate', 'ConOprDate1');
            $('#OperationDate').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                autoclose: true,
                startDate: ConOprDate1
            });
        }
        else {               

        }
    });
```

function AddDays(days) {

```
    var thisDate = new Date();

    thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + days);
    //return thisDate;

    return new Date(thisDate.getFullYear(), thisDate.getMonth(), thisDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing looks ok, except that you are making a mistake in line `if ($("#CaseType".val == "Plan_Only")) {`

This should be:
`if ($("#CaseType").val() == "Plan_Only") {`